# How to integrate a python script and execute it on Django

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, django-models, amazon-sns

what I want to happen is:

1. under `some_list_of_contacts = []` will be the numbers from my django model.
2. i will create a html template for this script that when I click the button it will execute this `send_sms.py`.
3. under `SMS_MESSAGE`it will be the latest data coming from django model with timestamp. for example `(As of {'timestamp'} the level is {'level'})`.

I'm a beginner on Django and Python, please how can I do these? Thanks!

*send_sms.py*

```
import boto3

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "<>"
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "<>"
AWS_REGION_NAME = "eu-west-1"

SENDER_ID = "Test"
SMS_MESSAGE = "Test"


client = boto3.client(
    "sns",
    aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    region_name=AWS_REGION_NAME
)

topic = client.create_topic(Name="notifications")
topic_arn = topic['TopicArn']

some_list_of_contacts = [
    '(must be numbers from django model)',
]


for number in some_list_of_contacts:
    client.subscribe(
        TopicArn=topic_arn,
        Protocol='sms',
        Endpoint=number 
    )


response = client.publish(
    Message=SMS_MESSAGE,
    TopicArn=topic_arn,
    MessageAttributes={
        'string': {
            'DataType': 'String',
            'StringValue': 'String',
        },
        'AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID': {
            'DataType': 'String',
            'StringValue': SENDER_ID
        }
    }
)

print(response)
print("MessageId:" + response["MessageId"])
print("HTTPStatusCode:" + str(response["ResponseMetadata"]["HTTPStatusCode"]))
```

Comment: What does your `views.py` look like?

Comment: I dont have any on my views.py right now, should I create a function based view or class based view?

Comment: Assumedly the `send_sms.py` will have to be triggered by an event or request (like a button press). `views.py` takes the request and returns a response, which might be what you're after. [More info can be found in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/views/)

Comment: Thanks! it worked. now I want to do is #1 how to fetch the mobile numbers stored inside my django table?